# Python Tools Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

Does anybody know if it's possible to open old(VS2015) Python solutions and projects  in Visual Studio 2017 RC ? VS 2017 cannot load my project, just saying it's incompatible. I was looking for some Python Tools in Modify Visual Studio option but couldn't find anything about it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft said on January 27, 2017 (build 26127.00)

> **Release Date: January 27, 2017 (build 26127.00)
>   Summary of Updates in this Release**
>
> Removed the Data Science and Python Development workloads as some of
>   the components weren’t meeting the release requirements, such as
>   translation to non-English languages. They will be available soon as
>   separate downloads. F# is still available in the .NET Desktop and .NET
>   Web development workloads. Upgrading to current version will remove
>   any previously installed Python and Data Science workloads/components.

Answer (score 4):

I found some more information here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2017/02/22/python-in-vs2017/

Seems like Python tools will be soon available! :)

> So here’s what we’re doing: around the time of the Visual Studio 2017 release, we will release a separate preview version of VS 2017 that includes Python support.
>
> Currently we are expecting Python support to be in the preview release for a few months, depending on our confidence in stability and user feedback. Once we move from preview to release, there will be an update and you’ll be able to select the Python workload in the stable release of Visual Studio.

Comment: you can also check out "VS 2017 Release" board on github (https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/projects/1) - it's almost done

Comment: Python Tools are now available in Preview version of VS2017, confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it is not possible as for now. Microsoft removed python tools from VS 2017 a week ago or so. They have written that Python Tools should be available as an add-on "soon".

Answer (score 1):

As of 10/05/2017 (Update 15.2), the Python and Data Science workloads are back in Visual Studio 2017.

Source:
[Visual Studio 2017 Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes)